# Can't get jQuery hide working

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I need a sanity check as I've spent about an hour trying to figure this out!

```
getRows().each(function() {
    alert(this);     // alerts '[object HTMLTableRowElement]', nothing wrong here
    this.hide();     // row not hidden - wtf?
    alert('hidden'); // no alert - more wtf!
});
```

What can be wrong that calling hide() is bombing out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside the `.each()` `this` is a DOM element (`HTMLTableRowElement`), you need to wrap it to make it a jQuery object again (which has the [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method) like this:

```
$(this).hide();
```

Without this, you're getting a method undefined error, because `HTMLTableRowElement` doesn't have the [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method :)  This error is also why the alert isn't firing afterwards, because execution stopped on the error.

Answer (score 2):

try `$(this).hide()`

Answer (score 2):

You don't get the 2nd alert because the previous line caused an error.  Change it to

```
$(this).hide();
```

`this` refers to the selected element, but that doesn't have a `hide` method.  You need to wrap it in a jQuery object which has the `hide` method.